# $x^3-3x^2+(a^2+2)x-a^2$ has 3 roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $\sin \tfrac{2\pi x_1}{3}+\sin \tfrac{2\pi x_3}{3}=2\sin \tfrac{2\pi x_2}{3}$. Find $a$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

$x^3-3x^2+(a^2+2)x-a^2$ has 3 roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that

$\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_1}{3}+\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_3}{3}=2\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_2}{3}$.

Find $a$

(Bulgari 1998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align*}x^3-3x^2+(a^2+2)x-a^2&=x(x^3-3x+2)+a^2(x-1)\\ &=[x(x-2)+a^2](x-1)\\ &=(x^2-2x+a^2)(x-1)\end{align*}

And the roots of $x^3-3x^2+(a^2+2)x-a^2$ are $1+\sqrt{1-a^2},\;1-\sqrt{1-a^2}\;\text{and}\; 1.$

If we set $a=1$ or $a=-1$, then the three roots are equal to $1$ and the equality holds.

Comment: If $x_2=1$ then the trig equation gives $\cos (2\pi\sqrt{1-a^2}/3)=1$, and your solutions follow.

Comment: @MarioG, How does the condition demand $x_1=x_2=x_3$

Comment: I mean, if we set $a=1,-1$ we get $\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_1}{3}+\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_3}{3}=2\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_2}{3}$ and also the three roots are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$\sin\dfrac{2\pi x_1}3+\sin \dfrac{2\pi x_3}3=2\sin\dfrac{\pi(x_1+x_3)}3\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1-x_3)}3$

As $x_1+x_2+x_3=3,$
$\sin\dfrac{\pi(x_1+x_3)}3=\sin\dfrac{\pi(3-x_2)}3=\sin\dfrac{\pi x_2}3$

So, we have $2\sin\dfrac{\pi x_2}3\left[\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1-x_3)}3-2\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_2)}3\right]=0$

Now, $\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_2)}3=\cos\dfrac{\pi\{3-(x_1+x_3)\}}3=-\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1+x_3)}3$

So, we have $2\sin\dfrac{\pi x_2}3\left[\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1-x_3)}3+2\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1+x_3)}3\right]=0$

As the product of two multiplicands is zero, at least one of them must be zero.

If $\sin\dfrac{\pi x_2}3=0,\dfrac{\pi x_2}3=n\pi\iff x_2=3n$ where $n$ is any integer

Else $\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1-x_3)}3+2\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1+x_3)}3=0$

$\iff3\cos\dfrac{\pi x_1}3\cos\dfrac{\pi x_3}3=\sin\dfrac{\pi x_1}3\sin\dfrac{\pi x_3}3$

$\iff\tan\dfrac{\pi x_1}3\tan\dfrac{\pi x_3}3=3$ which is not easily tractable

Comment: It's must be $2\sin\dfrac{\pi x_2}3\left[\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_1-x_3)}3-2\cos\dfrac{\pi(x_2)}3\right]=0$

Comment: @RoadHuman, Thanks for your feedback. But $x_2$  can be any multiple of $3,$ right? Have I missed something?

Comment: no $x_2=0.3$ only if $x_2=3k$  then $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=a^2+1$ so that $3k(3-3k)+a^2/3k=a^2+1$ hence $a^2=f(k) \Rightarrow k=0$ because $a^2 \le 1$ because $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 \ge 3(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)$

Comment: @RoadHuman, Why the roots have to be real?

Comment: i don't know $\sin (z)$ with $z$ is a complex number ??